# Django hitting MySQL even after select_related()?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-select-related

I'm trying to optimize the database calls coming from a fairly small Django app.  At current I have a couple of models, `Inquiry` and `InquiryStatus`.  When selecting all of the records from MySQL, I get a nice `JOIN` statement on the two tables, followed by many requests to the InquiryStatus table.  Why is Django still making individual requests if I've already done a `select_related()`?

**The models look like so:**

```
class InquiryStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25) 
    status_short = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-default_status", "status", "status_short"]

class Inquiry(models.Model):
    ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    status = models.ForeignKey(InquiryStatus)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-ts"]
```

**The view I threw together for debugging looks like so:**

```
def inquiries_list(request, template_name="inquiries/list_inquiries.js"):
    ## Notice the "print" on the following line.  Forces evaluation.
    print models.Inquiry.objects.select_related('status').all()
    return HttpResponse("CRAPSTICKS")
```

I've tried using `select_related(depth=1)`, with no change.  Each of the extraneous requests to the database are selecting one specific `id` in the `WHERE` clause.

### Update:

So there was one bit of very important code which should have been put in with the models:

```
from fullhistory import register_model
register_model(Inquiry)
register_model(InquiryStatus)
```

As a result, `fullhistory` was (for reasons I cannot fathom) pulling each individual result and parsing it.

Comment: Try to review your whole code. May be there is another place where you are getting objects without `select_related`

Comment: This is the only place that these models are being touched for this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [fullhistory](http://code.google.com/p/fullhistory/) ends up serializing the object, which evaluates each field in the instance to give it a base to compare to.

Take a look at the `get_all_data` function:

http://code.google.com/p/fullhistory/source/browse/trunk/fullhistory/fullhistory.py

If anybody wants to write up a detailed reason why this happens, I'll gladly mark that answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with lazy evaluation. Django only hits the DB if and when necessary, not when you invoke models.Inquiry.objects.select_related('status').all()

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#id3

Comment: Actually, if you look at the line where I have the query, it is a `print` line.  As a result, it is evaluated and generates a ton of queries.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown shouldn't actually generate any queries at all - QuerySets are only evaluated when necessary, not when they're defined, and you don't use the value anywhere so the execution won't be done.

Please show us a template or some other code that actually evaluates the qs - slices it, iterates, prints, or anything.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the line where I have the query, it is a `print` line.  As a result, it is evaluated and generates a ton of queries.